# Spring REST Jpa HATEOAS links not being created

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, jpa

I know that very similar questions have been asked here before, but I'm struggling to apply it to my problem.

I've recently started using jpa repositories for my data persistence needs and until now i had been content building HAL links that i wanted. Then i found that if i started using the @JoinTable and @JoinColumn annotations then i could have my links generated for me.

My problem is that when i hit the endpoint for my /posts, i don't get a HAL link for comments in the response.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="post")
public class Post {

@Id
@Column(name="id")
private @JsonIgnore Long id;

@Column(name="text")
private  String text;

@Column(name="sender_id")
private Long senderId;

@Column(name="event_id")
private Long eventId;

protected Post () {};

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

 public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public Long getSenderId() {
    return senderId;
}

public void setSenderId(Long senderId) {
    this.senderId = senderId;
}

public Long getEventId() {
    return eventId;
}

public void setEventId(Long eventId) {
    this.eventId = eventId;
}
}


@Entity
@Table(name="comment")
public class Comment  {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="id")
private @JsonIgnore Long id;

@Column(name="text")
private String comment;

@JsonIgnore
@Column(name="sender_id")
private Long senderId;

@JsonIgnore
@JoinColumn(name="post_id")
private Long post_id;

@JsonIgnore
@Column(name="deleted")
private Boolean deleted;

@ManyToOne
@JoinTable(name="post")
private Post post;

protected Comment() {};

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getComment() {
    return comment;
}

public void setComment(String comment) {
    this.comment = comment;
}

public Long getSenderId() {
    return senderId;
}

public void setSenderId(Long senderId) {
    this.senderId = senderId;
}

public Long getPostId() {
    return post_id;
}

public void setPostId(Long postId) {
    this.post_id = postId;
}

public Post getPost() {
    return post;
}

public void setPost(Post post) {
    this.post 
}
}
```

```
@RestController
public class CommentController {

private JdbcOperations jdbc;

private final CommentRepository commentDao;

@Autowired
public CommentController(CommentRepository postDao) {
    this.commentDao = postDao;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/comments", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Resources<Resource<Comment>>> getPagedList(@RequestParam(value = "user-id", required = true) long userId,
                                                                 @RequestParam(value = "page-size", required = false, defaultValue = "20") Long pageSize,
                                                                 @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false, defaultValue = "1") Long pageNum) {

    List<Comment> commentsList = (ArrayList) commentDao.findAll();

    List<Resource<Comment>> resourceList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Comment comment : commentsList) {

        Resource<Comment> postResource = new Resource<>(comment);

        postResource.add(linkTo(methodOn(CommentController.class)
                .getPagedList(userId, pageSize,pageNum)).withSelfRel());


        resourceList.add(postResource);
    }

    Resources<Resource<Comment>> resources = new Resources<>(resourceList,
            linkTo(methodOn(PostController.class)
                    .getPagedList(userId, pageSize, pageNum)).withSelfRel());

    return ResponseEntity.ok(resources);
}
```

```
@RestController
public class PostController {

private final PostRepository postDao;

@Autowired
public PostController(PostRepository postDao) {
    this.postDao = postDao;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/posts", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Resources<Resource<Post>>> getPagedList(@RequestParam(value="user-id", required = true) long userId,
                                                                 @RequestParam(value = "page-size", required = false, defaultValue = "20") Long pageSize,
                                                                 @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false, defaultValue = "1") Long pageNum) {

    List<Post> modelsList = (ArrayList) postDao.readBydeletedIsFalseOrderByCreated();
    List<Resource<Post>> resourceList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Post post : modelsList) {

        Resource<Post> resource = new Resource<>(post);

        resource.add(linkTo(methodOn(PostController.class)
                .getSpecificModel(post.getId())).withSelfRel());

        resource.add(linkTo(methodOn(UserController.class).getSpecificModel(post.getSenderId()))
                .withSelfRel().withRel("sender"));

        if (post.getEventId() != null) {
            resource.add(linkTo(methodOn(EventController.class)
                    .getSpecificModel(post.getEventId())).withSelfRel().withRel("event"));
        }

        resourceList.add(resource);
    }

    Resources<Resource<Post>> resources = new Resources<>(resourceList,
            linkTo(methodOn(PostController.class)
                    .getPagedList(userId, pageSize, pageNum)).withSelfRel());

    return ResponseEntity.ok(resources);
}
```

The response i get when i hit the /posts endpoint is this, with no link to comments:

```
http://localhost:8090/posts?user-id=1

{
  "_embedded": {
    "postList": [
      {
        "created": -84330000000,
        "text": "second post",
        "senderId": 2,
        "eventId": null,
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8090/posts/2"
          },
      "sender": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8090/users/2"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "created": 1286665200000,
    "text": "dfgtfy",
    "senderId": 1,
    "eventId": null,
    "_links": {
      "self": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8090/posts/1"
      },
      "sender": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8090/users/1"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "created": 1464735600000,
    "text": "third",
    "senderId": 1,
    "eventId": null,
    "_links": {
```

Comment: There's no clear association between posts and comments in the `Post` model.  (Also, as an aside, are you sure that a comment can have many posts?  Personally I'd make that a one-to-one and make the relationship between posts and comments many-to-many.  But this is just an aside.)

Comment: As per your object model, the Post is contained in Comment. A HAL link will not be generated if for requests on Post object. It will be generated for requests on Comment object.